# PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\FileDriver' not found

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I follow the instructions at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html step by step and have a Mongo server running however when I try to do :

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/StoreBundle
```

I get

```
Class 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\FileDriver' not found in /Users/username/Sites/myapp/vendor/doctrine-mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/Driver/XmlDriver.php on line 37
```

I am thinking something could be wrong with my parameters.ini file which still mentions MYSQL however the link above did not mention anything about that:

```
[parameters]
    database_driver="pdo_mysql"
    database_host="localhost"
    database_port=""
    database_name="somedb"
    database_user="root"
    database_password="mypassword"
    mailer_transport="smtp"
    mailer_host="localhost"
    mailer_user=""
    mailer_password=""
    locale="en"
    secret="093faacf47bcdcdcdcdcdc9d152fc8b"
```

what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I have Doctrine Common downloaded and here is my registerNameSpaces function:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony'          => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
    'Sensio'           => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'JMS'              => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Doctrine\\Common' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
    'Doctrine\\DBAL'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
    'Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB'    => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-mongodb-odm/lib',
    'Doctrine\\MongoDB'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-mongodb/lib',
    'Doctrine'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',
    'Monolog'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/monolog/src',
    'Assetic'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/assetic/src',
    'Metadata'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/metadata/src',
    'FOS'              => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'FOS\\Rest'        => __DIR__.'/../vendor/fos',
    'JMS'              => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
));
```

my deps file:

```
[symfony]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=origin/2.0

[twig]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git
    version=v1.8.2

[monolog]
    git=http://github.com/Seldaek/monolog.git
    version=1.0.2

[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.1.4

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.1.7

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.1.7

[swiftmailer]
    git=http://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git
    version=v4.2.0

[assetic]
    git=http://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic.git
    version=v1.0.3

[twig-extensions]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions.git

[metadata]
    git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/metadata.git
    version=1.0.0

[SensioFrameworkExtraBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[JMSSecurityExtraBundle]
    git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle
    version=origin/1.0.x

[SensioDistributionBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[SensioGeneratorBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[AsseticBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
    version=origin/2.0


[FOSUserBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/UserBundle
    version=1.2.0

[FOSRest]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest.git
    target=fos/FOS/Rest

[FOSRestBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/RestBundle

[JMSSerializerBundle]
    git=git://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle.git
    target=bundles/JMS/SerializerBundle


[doctrine-mongodb]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/mongodb.git

[doctrine-mongodb-odm]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm.git

[DoctrineMongoDBBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMongoDBBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

I also do not see a Driver folder under mapping. I have done a php bin/vendors install --reinstall bu even that doesnt help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update the three: DBAL, Common and ORM. The three have been released at the same time. So you should use version 2.2 for the 3.

Here is the blog post http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-2-2-final.html

Hope this helps, it worked for me.

Comment: Is the page updated? Current page returns 404 - https://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-2-2-final.html

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine MongoDB ODM was recently refactored to utilize Doctrine Common's mapping API, which exists in version 2.2+ (see PR's [#350](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/350) and [#370](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/370)). In turn, both the 2.0 and master branches of the bundle were updated (PR [#124](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/pull/124)).

Based on your deps file, you're using Doctrine Common 2.1.x, which doesn't contain the required classes. You can either bump Common to 2.2, which should be compatible with Symfony 2.0, or lock ODM and the bundle to an earlier commit hash before those PR's were merged. Checking the `composer.json` files in each repository would be a good way to keep track of these dependencies, even if you aren't using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/). Hopefully, we'll have tags on the Mongo ODM repositories soon, which should alleviate this headache in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have Doctrine Common installed, or you don't have it registered in your autoloader. Install it (link: https://github.com/doctrine/common) or redownload the sf2 standard edition.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I do have it downloaded and I have updated my question above. Any other tips? It works fine when I remove all the Mongo stuff and go back to regular MySQL Doctrine